# Tooltip not showing in Hearthstone Decktracker plugin

Tags: wpf, plugins

I am writing a plugin for Hearthstone Decktracker, and am adding a tooltip to each of the items that get generated in an ItemsControl.

If I attach the debugger to HearthstoneDeckTracker, I can see the items have a tooltip in the VisualTree, but the tooltip never shows when I mouseover the item.

If anyone were able to help with this problem, it would require that they have HDT and Hearthstone, but I feel the problem is more of a WPF issue than a DeckTracker issue.

There are instructions on creating a plugin at https://github.com/HearthSim/Hearthstone-Deck-Tracker/wiki/Creating-Plugins

To replicate this, you could use the example project provided by HDT Github at https://github.com/andburn/hdt-plugin-example.

Adding a tooltip to the DataTemplate in CurvyList.xaml should be able to show you what I am seeing.

Instead of

```
    <DataTemplate>
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Background}" Height="34" Width="217" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

you would have (sorry... doing this off top of my head, so syntax may be incorrect)

```
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Background}" Height="34" Width="217" >
                <Rectangle.Tooltip>
                   <Textblock Text="Hello World" />
                </Rectangle.Tooltip>
            </Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
```

I have posted this same question on the official Discord channel, but I don't think it is currently being viewed, so I am going to give it a shot here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

cannot you just add the `tooltip` directly into the rectangle?

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Background}" ToolTip="Hello World" Height="34" Width="217" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  You could add the tooltip to the rectangle, but the same issue exists (and ultimately, I want to create a more complex tooltip)... I think it has to do with the way that DeckTracker is displaying the plugin.. It's sort of like the hittest isn't finding the item that the tooltip is applied to.